# VisualStudio 2010 , Shellexecute in calling a .py file is not working. ( but it works in VS2012 )

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010

This is how my string for the shell execute looks like.

`ShellExecute(0, "open", "cmd.exe", strExecute.c_str(), 0, SW_HIDE);`

```
strExecute =  "cmd.exe /c cd C:\Program Files\Siemens\NX 8.5&&Bolt_V2.py
               C:\System\Input.txt C:\System\Output.txt"
```

I am first traversing to the current directory where the .py file exists and then **"&&"** is used to pass in the 2'nd command which contains the PYTHON file and the parameters to pass in.
Would really be helpful if I can find help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may have to backslash-escape all the backslashes and in any file paths and put backslash-escapeed double quotes around any with embedded space characters. For example: `...\"C:\\Program Files\\Siemens\NX 8.5\"&&...`.

Comment: Hi matinaeu, I managed to do this, but unfortunately it still isnt working. Can you kindly correct me, please.          cmd.exe /c cd  "C:\Program Files\Siemens\NX 8.5"&&Bolt_V2.py C:\Old_System\Ajoy\OldSystem\Demos\BoltmeshInput.txt C:\Old_System\Ajoy\OldSystem\Demos\BoltmeshInput.inp true.   The comments after the Bolt_V2.py are parameters to the .py file. Hence I thought those should not come under quotes.

Comment: Else can I know if there is something else other than the "&&" command to pass the 2'nd set of commands to the exeution. I have a feeling that this could also be one of the reasons its failing.

Comment: Sorry. I guess the whole problem was with the Python script. There seems to be some version conflict with the file.